# Ionic 2 how to toggle ion-header size

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Here is the basic code I have:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title align="center" (click)="somehowToggleExpand()">
      Some really really long text here...
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

By default, this header bar is limited to a height of one line and text inside it is truncated. How can I make it so clicking the header bar toggles expanding (dropping down) the header to show all the text?

Comment: you mean menu toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7xXc1Y8x1Eu0HEuESuou?p=preview)

To remove the truncated text you can add a class using [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) that removes non-wrapping text.

## CSS

```
.expanded .toolbar-title {
  white-space: initial;
}
```

## Component

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  expanded = false;
  somehowToggleExpand() {
    this.expanded = true;
  }
}
```

## Header HTML

```
<ion-header [ngClass]="{'expanded': expanded}">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title align="center" (click)="somehowToggleExpand()">
      Some really really long text here
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

## [Update](https://plnkr.co/edit/7xXc1Y8x1Eu0HEuESuou?p=preview) - Expanding `ion-header` CSS

To allow the `ion-header` to expand, add this to your CSS

```
.expanded ion-title {
  position: initial;
}
```

Comment: This does un-truncate text but how can we also resize the header bar to accommodate all the un-truncated text?

Comment: I updated the answer and it should work now. Let me know if there's anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/)

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="doClick()">
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```